# Sandboxing Steam and it‘s games via Flatpak

Tags: 18.04, steam, flatpak

I have some questions when I install steam via flatpak.

1st: Is Steam sandboxed ? 
2nd: Are the games that I play sandboxed ? 
3rd: How the updating of steam and it‘s games works ?

Comment: Those are too many good questions. [Steam flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.valvesoftware.Steam) as any flatpak is "sandboxed" ([not much](https://flatkill.org/)).